# How to make a generic type that can both pick and make properties readonly?

Tags: typescript

I have two generic types `MyPick` and `MyReadonly`. I would like to combine them together, because the line `const myNewObject: MyPick<MyInterface, PropsToPick> & MyReadonly<MyInterface, PropsToMakeReadonly> = myObject` is diffucult to read and understand. How would you go about simplifying/improving this code?

```
interface MyInterface {
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
  c?: string;
}

type PropsToPick = "a" | "b"
type PropsToMakeReadonly = "a"

type MyPick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in K]: T[P];
};
type MyReadonly<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  readonly [P in K]: T[P];
}

const myObject:MyInterface = { a: '1', b: '2' }
const myNewObject: MyPick<MyInterface, PropsToPick> & MyReadonly<MyInterface, PropsToMakeReadonly> = myObject

myNewObject.a = '11' // FAILS, BECAUSE IT'S READONLY
myNewObject.b = '22'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly shorter and verifies that readonly props are "picked":

```
type PickAndReadonly<T, PK extends keyof T, RK extends PK> = Pick<T, PK> & Readonly<Pick<T, RK>>;

const myNewObject: PickAndReadonly<MyInterface, PropsToPick, PropsToMakeReadonly> = myObject
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlk4B%20ALmQGcwpQBzAbhOQCMrb6nXSEudBiBZEAvkSJh0ABxQAFKAHsZNACpL5wBAGtkAXmQAiOEeQAfY%20yNTZC5ao2o4OiACUIcACZKQAG3QDY1NJaTlkLV0AQRAvD29fAIAeNQAaCIBpZAgAD0hYmmRXdCUYZDTkNyzc-K9C%20QyAPiDInRT0huaAMkrPH390JNb2yqbG1iIEXzpkAFt0AHl2ACsIBDBKDGxIWEQUQwIyagByAEZj9PYTgCZj5AkpkBn5gDkIAHcl1fXqVpi4vqJQZbHC7JAdBzqTTaHQQlRQ5yueL9ALNQzzL5rMCSV4fTHrAB0cCCZ3OyAA9OTkAAxKKYAAyAGV0gAhACiAGEogBVRls5CYNTHRmVNlRAAiCxe9IAmkRcZ8VliCewSddbkA)

Answer (score 1):

One more utility type can help:

```
type MyType<T, P extends keyof T, R extends P> = MyPick<T, P> & MyReadonly<T, R>

const myNewObject: MyType<MyInterface, PropsToPick, PropsToMakeReadonly> = myObject
```